# Benchmarking functions

Tags: c, microcontroller, avr

I've written the C code - that is below - to have a benchmark of some functions. The main purpose of this benchmark is to test these functions on the AVR AT Tiny85, but also on a PC (for now I'm using an atmega168 instead of the AT Tiny85 - but is almost the same).

This benchmark executes a big number of loops for each function it has to test and for a "void" function that receives the same parameters of the function to be tested, but executes only a return. At the end of the loops of each functions it writes a label and a time expressed in usec. That time is the duration of the loops for the function specified by the label.

I might think that if I subtract the benchmark time of the "void" function from the benchmark time of a function to be tested and I divide the result for the number of loops, I've a sufficient information about the duration of the function to be tested. But this is not true because interrupts (even just what to measure time).

In any case I think this benchmark is able to indicate me the fastest function. What's your opinion? Have you suggestion about?

Here an output example:

```
void 2110168
norm 2121500
base 2337196
basl 2450964
basw 2333980
ant4 2235236
ant5 2242904
unro 2270484
unrl 2590444
vect 2754188
vesw 2732472
```

The link between the label and the function may be seen looking at the lookup table "static fntest_t fnt" in the benchmark code.

The code I've reported below may be compiled on PC using GCC 64bit (32bit with a few modifications because warnings) or on AVR using Arduino environment / avr-gcc.

Below is the benchmark code. The type test_t I used in the code is "typedefined" as uint16_t in the umul.h file (the purpose of this typedef was to change easily the type of the values managed/returned by the functions, but now is possible only for a few of those!)

```
#ifdef __AVR__
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <HardwareSerial.h>
#include <string.h>
#else
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include "timefn.h"
#endif

#include "umul.h"

#ifndef UNUSED
#define UNUSED(x) (void)(x)
#endif

typedef test_t fn_t(test_t a,test_t b);

typedef struct fntest_s {
    fn_t * fn;
    char * msg;
} fntest_t;

test_t nullfn(test_t a,test_t b);
#ifndef __AVR__
uint32_t micros();
#endif

static fntest_t fnt[]={
    {nullfn,(char *)"void"},
    {umul16_normal,(char *)"normal"},
    {umul16_base,(char *)"base"},
    {umul16_baseandlogic,(char *)"basl"},
    {umul16_baseswap,(char *)"basw"},
    {umul16_Antonio4,(char *)"ant4"},
    {umul16_Antonio5,(char *)"ant5"},
    {umul16_unrolled,(char *)"unro"},
    {umul16_unrolledandlogic,(char *)"unrl"},
    {umul16_vect,(char *)"vect"},
    {umul16_vectswap,(char *)"vesw"}
};

#ifndef __AVR__
uint32_t micros()
{
    struct timeval t;
    gettimeofday(&t,NULL);

    return (t.tv_sec*1000000UL+t.tv_usec);
}
#endif

test_t nullfn(test_t a,test_t b)
{
    UNUSED(a);UNUSED(b);
    return 0;
}

test_t umultry()
{
#ifdef __AVR__
#define RUNS 20000
static char strbuf[50];
#else
#define RUNS 10000000
#endif

    unsigned int i,j,k;
    uint32_t x;

    test_t ix,iy;
    static test_t z[16];

    for(j=0;j<5;j++) {
        for(k=0;k<sizeof(fnt)/sizeof(fntest_t);k++) {
            x=micros();srand(x);
            for(i=0;i<RUNS;i++) {
                ix=rand();iy=rand();
                z[i&0xF]+=fnt[k].fn(ix,iy);
            }
            x=micros()-x;
#ifdef __AVR__
            sprintf(strbuf,"%s %lu\n",fnt[k].msg, x);
            Serial.print(strbuf);
#else
            printf("%s %u\n",fnt[k].msg, x);
#endif
        }
        for(i=0;i<16;i++) {
            z[0]+=z[i]; /* To avoid warn unused and the optimizations don't evaluate z[]*/
        }

#ifdef __AVR__
        Serial.println("----------------");
#else
        puts("----------------");
#endif
    }

    return z[0];
}

#ifdef __AVR__
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println(F("Starting..."));
}

void loop()
{
    umultry();
    for(;;);
}
#else
int main(void)
{
    puts("Starting...");
    return umultry();
}
#endif
```

Here are the functions to be tested:

```
#include "umul.h"

test_t umul16_normal(test_t a, test_t b)
{
    return a*b;
}

test_t umul16_unrolled(test_t a, test_t b)
{
test_t result=0;

#define UMUL16_STEP(a, b, shift) \
    if ((b) & (1U << (shift))) result += (a<<shift);

    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 0);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 1);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 2);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 3);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 4);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 5);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 6);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 7);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 8);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 9);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 10);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 11);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 12);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 13);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 14);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 15);

    return result;
#undef UMUL16_STEP
}

test_t umul16_unrolledandlogic(test_t a, test_t b)
{
test_t result=0;
#define UMUL16_STEP(a, b, shift) \
/*    if ((b) & (1U << (shift))) result += (a<<shift);*/\
    result+=  ((0 - !(!((b&(1U<<(shift)))))) & (a<<(shift)));

    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 0);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 1);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 2);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 3);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 4);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 5);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 6);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 7);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 8);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 9);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 10);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 11);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 12);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 13);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 14);
    UMUL16_STEP(a, b, 15);

    return result;
#undef UMUL16_STEP
}

test_t umul16_Antonio5(test_t a, test_t b)
{
    test_t res = 0;

    uint8_t b0 = b & 0xff; //This should be optimized away
    uint8_t b1 = b >>8; //This should be optimized away

    //Swapping probably doesn't make much sense anymore
    if ( (b1 & 1) )
        res+=(test_t)((uint8_t)(a && 0xff))*256;
    //Hopefully the compiler understands it has simply to add the low 8bit register of a to the high 8bit register of res

    if ( (b0 & 1) )
        res+=a;

    b1>>=1;
    b0>>=1;
    while (b0) {///N cycles, maximum 7
        a+=a;
        if ( (b1 & 1) )
            res+=(test_t)((uint8_t)(a & 0xff))*256;
        if ( (b0 & 1) )
            res+=a;
        b1>>=1;
        b0>>=1; //I try to put as last the one that will leave the carry flag in the desired state
    }

    uint8_t a0 = a & 0xff; //Again, not a real copy but a register selection

    while (b1) {///P cycles, maximum 7 - N cycles
        a0+=a0;
        if ( (b1 & 1) )
            res+=(test_t) a0 * 256;
        b1>>=1;
    }
    return res;
}

test_t umul16_base(test_t a, test_t b)
{
    test_t res=0;

    while (b) {
        if ( (b & 1) )
            res+=a;
        b>>=1;
        a+=a;
    }

    return res;
}

test_t umul16_baseandlogic(test_t a, test_t b)
{
    test_t res=0;

    while (b) {
        //if ( (b & 1) )
        //    res+=a;
        res+=  ((0 - !(!(b&1))) & a);
        b>>=1;
        a+=a;
    }

    return res;
}

test_t umul16_baseswap(test_t a, test_t b)
{
    test_t res;

    if (a<b) {
        res=a;
        a=b;
        b=res;
    }

    res=0;
    while (b) {
        if ( (b & 1) )
            res+=a;
        b>>=1;
        a+=a;
    }

    return res;
}

test_t umul16_Antonio4(test_t a, test_t b)
{
    uint8_t res1 = 0;

    uint8_t a0 = a & 0xff; //This effectively needs to copy the data
    uint8_t b0 = b & 0xff; //This should be optimized away
    uint8_t b1 = b >>8; //This should be optimized away

    //Here a0 and b1 could be swapped (to have b1 < a0)
    if ( (b1 & 1) )
        res1+=a0;
    b1>>=1;
    while (b1) {///Maximum 7 cycles
        a0+=a0;
        if ( (b1 & 1) )
            res1+=a0;
        b1>>=1;
    }

    test_t res = (test_t) res1 * 256; //Should be optimized away, it's not even a copy!

    //Here swapping wouldn't make much sense
    if ( (b0 & 1) )
        res+=a;
    b0>>=1;
    while (b0) {///Maximum 7 cycles
        a+=a;
        if ( (b0 & 1) )
            res+=a;
        b0>>=1;
    }

    return res;
}

test_t umul16_vect(test_t a, test_t b)
{
    test_t c[2];

    c[0]=0;c[1]=a;a=0;
    while (b) {
        a+=c[(b & 1)];
        b>>=1;
        c[1]+=c[1];
    }

    return a;
}

test_t umul16_vectswap(test_t a, test_t b)
{
    test_t c[2];

    if (a<b) {
        c[1]=b;
        b=a;
        a=c[1];
    }

    c[0]=0;c[1]=a;a=0;
    while (b) {
        a+=c[(b & 1)];
        b>>=1;
        c[1]+=c[1];
    }

    return a;
}

test_t udiv_(test_t n,test_t d, test_t *r)
{
    test_t q = 0,i,r_;

    r_=0;
    if (d == 0) return (test_t)-1U; //error

    i= ( (test_t)(1) << ((sizeof(n)<<3)-1) );
    for (;i!=0;i>>=1) {
        r_ <<= 1;

        if (n&i)
            r_ |= 1;

        if (r_ >= d) {
            r_ -= d;
            q |= i;
        }
    }
    if (r!=NULL)
        *r=r_;

    return q;
}
```

Here is the include file umul.h for the functions to be tested:

```
#ifndef __UMUL_H
#define __UMUL_H

#ifdef __AVR_ATtiny85__
typedef signed int int8_t __attribute__((__mode__(__QI__)));
typedef unsigned int uint8_t __attribute__((__mode__(__QI__)));
typedef signed int int16_t __attribute__ ((__mode__ (__HI__)));
typedef unsigned int uint16_t __attribute__ ((__mode__ (__HI__)));
typedef signed int int32_t __attribute__ ((__mode__ (__SI__)));
typedef unsigned int uint32_t __attribute__ ((__mode__ (__SI__)));
typedef signed int int64_t __attribute__((__mode__(__DI__)));
typedef unsigned int uint64_t __attribute__((__mode__(__DI__)));

#define NULL 0
#else
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#endif

typedef uint16_t test_t;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

test_t umul16_normal(test_t a, test_t b);
test_t umul16_unrolled(test_t a, test_t b);
test_t umul16_unrolledandlogic(test_t a, test_t b);
test_t umul16_Antonio5(test_t a, test_t b);
test_t umul16_base(test_t a, test_t b);
test_t umul16_baseswap(test_t a, test_t b);
test_t umul16_Antonio4(test_t a, test_t b);
test_t umul16_vect(test_t a, test_t b);
test_t umul16_vectswap(test_t a, test_t b);
test_t umul16_baseandlogic(test_t a, test_t b);
    test_t udiv_(test_t n,test_t d, test_t *r);
} // extern "C"
#endif

#endif
```

Comment: Well the risk with this kind of benchmark is that the compiler will see you're doing nothing with the values and will try to optimize it away

Comment: @meneldal. Yes, I know, I tried to obtain the values of the functions are used! I think I succeeded, but I've posted here especially with regard to figure out if it's true what I think!

Comment: I was reading that `rand` might not be sufficient for your needs, you have to check what's the value of 'RAND_MAX' in your system (it could be just 32767, that is less than 65536). http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/RAND_MAX/. See also http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/.

Comment: @SergioFormiggini Regarding the other question: `umul16_normal` seems the fastest, can you send me also the assembly generated for that? The device where you are testing maybe has a multiplier after all.

Comment: That is because I'm using an ATmega168 that has the instruction mul then you don't care of umul_normal. I'm thinking to send you all the asm of umul.c ... :) umul_normal contains: return a*b!

Answer (score 1):

Normally to remove the influence of interruptions you simply repeat the test a few times and keep the fastest response as measurement.

The repetition is also needed for complex CPUs like x86 to remove dependency on current cache content and branch predictor statistics.

On modern CPUs is also very important to be sure that the clock is fixed (most modern CPUs automatically modulate the clock to reduce heating/consumption when the CPU is mostly idling and it may require some time for the clock control logic to get back to full speed).

Comment: The test I've written executes each function 10,000,000 times on the PC and 20,000 times on the AVR. This loops are re-executed 5 times. On the PC I see the first times are often different from the 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th; the latter differ by a few micro.

Comment: I would say the fastest response might not represent as much the reality as lets say the 10th percentile. It also depends if you want to consider the worse cases performance or not. On embedded systems usually the worse case is what matters.

Comment: @meneldal: it depends on what you want to measure. The faster response is to measure the actual function code time as interruptions can only slow it down; this kind of measurement is normally done on tiny code fragments (for example to decide what is the best implementation to use for a part of an algorithm). Real measurement for timing requirements is instead done on the full function running on real data and in that case of course it's the average or slowest response that is important.

Comment: My interest (although the algorithm evaluates average time) is to understand the worst case! But I think that the function that had the worst average time most likely is that having the worst worst case! :) This idea should be true on AVR 8 bit systems.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of opportunity for improvements in your benchmarking code.

First of all, I would generate the random input data at the beginning, and store it in some buffer. There are 2 reasons: first you will be able to feed the same data to all algorithms, second you do not pollute your timings with random generations routines.

For `srand` you can even hardcode a seed number (for example 0) to keep your data exactly the same in consecutive benchmarks.

You should also check if changing the order in which you test your functions changes the timing you get.

By the way, I think you should also check if all your functions are correct, e.g. if they give the same result given the same inputs.

Which optimization flags did you set? I confirm there's a risk your null function is optimized away, maybe put a `return a-b;` or something similar.

---

Probably the following it's not relevant at all, if I understand correctly and `z` is just a dummy variable.

I believe you should add an initialization for `z`, namely:

```
   for(i=0;i<16;i++) {
        z[i] = 0;
    }
```

Here:

```
   for(i=0;i<16;i++) {
        z[0]+=z[i]; /* To avoid warn unused and the optimizations don't evaluate z[]*/
    }
```

should be instead:

```
   for(i=1;i<16;i++) {
        z[0]+=z[i]; /* To avoid warn unused and the optimizations don't evaluate z[]*/
    }
```

Otherwise you sum `z[0]` 2 times in the final result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The idea to compute the random values before the test execution is good, but there's a memory problem, The program executes 20,000 loops with different numbers and the real target (not PC) has no memory to take two 40Kb vectors. The idea of the fixed seed seems better. I think that fixing it for all steps the rand function should generate the same sequence. It's also a good idea to change the order of the in-testing functions, that should be useful on CPU as are those of the PC, but not for AVRs.

Comment: I've not already tested in a effective way if all the functions give the same results. That should be done! The z[x] results have no means for the test purpose, then I've "forgotten" to initialize them! The for loop the sums them was inserted to avoid the compiler understand that they are useless.

Comment: There's my thoughts also about optimization. I've compiled (using gcc) this benchmark taking in accout the optimization result (especially for the PC). I've used -O0 -O2 -Os e -Ofast. The idea to use a lookup table is due to avoid the functions may be not called (because optimizations) using the call instruction and thus gaining a simple way to manage more functions are tested inside the same loop.

Comment: The benchmark does an other operation, it  is to call a "void" function that doesn't do nothing else a return. The test results of this function allows a sufficient estimate of the loop load.

Comment: @SergioFormiggini It would really improve the quality if the benchmark separated random input generation from actual testing. If 80Kb is not available, see what you can get, and maybe you can do alternate several cycles of generation and time measurement.

Comment: the AVR micros has really a small RAM memory. The Atmega168 that I'm using (waiting for the tiny84/85) has 1Kb RAM. It's not a PC! It's a little single chip with a great set of RISC instruction, with some ADC and digital I/O closed into an 8 pin chip (Tiny 85).

Comment: @SergioFormiggini Then, I would say, just split the test in several batches with, let's say, 100 number pairs (100x2x2 = 400bytes). I mean, I hope you mean 1KByte, not 1Kbit! The point is that random generation is really expensive, far more expensive than the multiplication you are trying to test.

Comment: Yes I know that random functions are more expensive than multiplications! That is why I have also used to test a "void" function! The difference should be the time used from the function. Making some calculation this assumption (on AVRs) seems true!

Comment: @SergioFormiggini Yep, I understand your plan. I think it is reasonable, but if you could eradicate the problem completely it would be preferable. Each operation you includes add noise to the time measures, and that noise might be bigger than the signal you are trying to measure.

Comment: It's good and true what you're saying and is one of the answers I expected when I post this questions! I've to find something  approaching a solution best fitting the idea to measure the functions time comsumption, but I think that for the purpose to understand what of this solution is faster on AVRs this benchmark is not so bad!